# increment variable on set interval using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

First of all this is the mini javascript script:

```
 f = 1
 $(".thumb").hover(function() {
       intervalId = setInterval($(this).text(f++), 400));
  });
```

Im trying to get the .thumb text to increase while the users moise is over it, It increases when i hover out and hover over again, but i want to increase while the user is hovered on top of the element.

Comment: Please explain your problem more clearly. I don't understand what you mean by "It increases when i hover out and hover over again, but i want to increase while the user is hovered on top of the element."

Comment: I think he means he wants the number to continually increment when the mouse is over it, but it only increments once for each time he moves the mouse over it.  Did I understand that correctly?

Comment: yes exactly @AdamPlocher i want to constantly increase!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to pass an actual function to `setInterval()` like this:

```
 f = 1
 $(".thumb").hover(function() {
       var self = $(this);
       intervalId = setInterval(function() {self.text(f++)}, 400));
  });
```

What you are doing in your original code is passing the result of calling `$(this).text(f++)` which executes immediately to `setInterval()`.  Since that doesn't return a function, there is no callback function for `setInterval()` so nothing runs on the interval.

---

If you also want to stop the interval when you stop hovering, then you could do this:

```
 var f = 1;
 var intervalId;
 $(".thumb").hover(function() {
     var self = $(this);
     if (intervalId) {
         clearInterval(intervalId);
     }
     intervalId = setInterval(function() {self.text(f++)}, 400));
 }, function() {
     f = 1;
     clearInterval(intervalId);
     intervalId = null;
 });
```

Comment: This doesn't stop when the user mouses off, and triggers again and starts going faster when there's multiple mouseovers.

Comment: @MattDiamant - yes, the OP needs to extend their code to stop the interval when the hover stops if that is the behavior they want.  I wasn't aware the OP was asking for help with that.  I've added that option to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
var f = 1,
    intervalId;

$(".thumb").hover(function () {
    $this = $(this);
    intervalId = setInterval(function () {
        $this.text(f++);
    }, 100);
}, function () {
    clearInterval(intervalId);
});
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/n74VW/)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a fiddle that does what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/2pdnP/

```
var f = 1;
var intervalId = null;
 $(".thumb").hover(function() {
    var self = this;
    intervalId = setInterval(function() {$(self).text(f++)}, 400);
 }, function () {
    clearInterval(intervalId);
 });
```

You need to have intervalId defined outside of your hoverIn scope, and then deactivate it when you hover out.

Answer (score 0):

This works, but there might be a simpler way:

```
<script>
 var f = 1
 var intervalId;
 var started = false;

 $(".thumb").hover(function() {
    started = true;
  },
  function () {
    started = false;
  });

  intervalId = setInterval(incrementDiv, 400);

  function incrementDiv() {
    if (started) {
        $(".thumb").text(f++);
    }
  }
</script>
```

This will start incrementing the value while the mouse is hovered over the element, and stop when the mouse cursor moves away.